# Настройка библиотеки микроконтроллера STM32F303VCT, архитектура ARM

Tags: микроконтроллеры, stm32

Требуется настроить стандартные библиотеки для микроконтроллера STM32F303VCT на архитектуре ARM(что я узнал пройдя по ссылки на плате - [ссылка](https://www.st.com/stm32f3discovery), для дальнейшей с ним работы. Уже перепробовал множество способов(поскольку я совсем новичок в этой сфере, я не знаю, что необходимо, а без чего можно обойтись, поэтому меня крайне беспокоит, что я не могу подключить основные, отвечающие за периферию библиотеки), просто включал в проекте, настраивал автоподключение в Keil uvision 5, вроде бы они даже видны проекту, но при попытке подключать основной заголовочный файл справа от номера строки кода возникает красный текст, а при наведении гласит: "fatal error: 'stm32f3xx.h' file not found", что предотвращает всякие попытки сборок проекта, хотя этот самый 'stm32f3xx.h' находится в той же директории(хотя у меня это stm32f30x.h, если я правильно понял x означает, что цифра может быть любой, хотя возможно я ошибаюсь). Порядок моей изначальной настройки был следующим:
 1. Установка keil uvision 5.
 2. Установка драйверов для микроконтроллера STM32F303
 3. Установка ST Link-Utility
 4. Установка ST cube MX
Сам вопрос заключается в том: как же мне все таки начать работу с подключенной библиотекой? Или можно ли этим как-то пренебречь? Как мне уже начать работать с платой?
Возможно я что-то не так настроил? Может быть я неправильно что-то подключаю? Прошу, если так поправьте меня и опишите правильный алгоритм действий! Я убил уже весь день, просто, чтобы подключить один заголовочный файл, мне не терпится разбираться с таймером, мигать светодиодом и работать с кнопками, но по сравнению с ардуино, с которого я недавно перешёл это просто какой-то ад. Прошу, помогите!

Comment: Пути поиска заголовочных файлов должны задаваться в параметрах командной строки компилятора. В различных средах разработки обычно есть настройки проекта, в которых эти пути можно указать. Попробуйте открыть настройки вашего проекта и указать там пути поиска заголовков.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос исчерпан. Я пытался настроить и пути автоматического выбора библиотек(через устанавливаемые пакеты) и заливать сами библиотеки в проект - нужно было выбрать одно из двух. Библиотеки тоже нашёл, также возможно было, как уже было сказано, настроить путь к библиотеке в настройках проекта.